# Bad quality when printing PDF to Zebra GK420t label printer

Tags: printing

I just got a Zebra GK420t label print which I use in direct termo mode.
I managed to get it to print the PDF:s I need to print after setting up the media size correctly. But the quality is not good. The quality of the test page however is much better.

Anybody know what needs to be done to improve the quality? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5 on this machine.

Thanks!

[image: label image]